# TypeError: state.items is not iterable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know in React-Redux and I'm constantly getting stuck in the same error again and again - "TypeError: state.items is not iterable" I tried all types of solutions but didn't succeed.

I have an eCommerce app that has add to basket buttons - when the person clicks on the addToBasket button the product gets added to the basket in my global state and the problem- the addToBasket button is not working when I try adding an item again it shows the error. "TypeError: state.items is not iterable" Here is my code in my reducer-

```js
import { createReducer } from "reduxsauce";
import { BasketTypes } from "store/actions/Basket";


export const INITIAL_STATE = {
  items:[],
};


export const addToBasket = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => ({ ...state, items: [...state.items , action.payload]});



export const HANDLERS = {
  [BasketTypes.ADD_TO_BASKET]: addToBasket,
 
};

export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, HANDLERS);
```

This is my action code:

```js
import { createActions } from "reduxsauce";

const { Types, Creators } = createActions(
  {
    addToBasket: ["payload"],
    
  },
  {}
); // options - the 2nd parameter is optional

export const BasketTypes = Types;
export default Creators;
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

Comment: `console.log(state)` please, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you call that action with `{}`(Empty Object).
Actually it is not exactly `undefined`. so your `INITAL_STATE` doesn't working

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problem.
I had an array in my state object & I  was initialized an empty object in createStore as second argument & it was making error until that array was invoked in my code. I removed the empty object from createStore & the problem solved.
It seems it was being overridden by that & my initializations in my reducer was being deleted so the codes couldn't access that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Well in my case i was calling state after setting variable into it . 
So it was looking like : 

   patchState({
   Stuff:[...[],...state.Stuff]
   })

So here of our intern work on the bug and he wanted to clean state but with wrong method .
So clear ans would be check the method of state calling might be error while calling so be clear about it . 

And after to it i took it and solved via calling initial state and deified empty array as initial state .
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).